# Is this "Boost" / File Manager app a true system app or malware?

Tags: malware

I installed this app after I received a notification on my lock screen informing me that a new system app was available for download. Seeing that the app was listed as an update to the "File Manager" app, I assumed it was safe and downloaded it. Now it's filling my lock screen with spammy looking notifications, prompting me to "boost" my phone to free disk space and memory.

The original **File Manager** app that shipped with my Android was very unobtrusive and was located in the Settings app on the phone. It never interfered with anything I was doing. It never sent me twice-daily notifications to 'clean my system', 'boost my phone' or 'free up RAM'. That is what makes me think this app is really malware posing as a true system app and tricking Android into installing it.

There is no way to uninstall it or disable it. The  original File Manager app appeared alongside this app for a while, but the original app was recently removed and no longer shows up. My phone is lagging and other apps are crashing or not performing well since I installed this app. Additionally, this "Boost" app that has installed itself on my home screen is full of ads. No true Android system app has ever contained ads that I have seen, so this is very fishy. Also, the fact that it cannot be disabled is also very suspect.

I am suspicious that it is affecting my phone in a negative way and I want it gone! I cannot imagine that Android would release a "system app" that was full of ads. PLEASE HELP!

The device affected is an **Alcatel Fierce 4 5056N** running **Android 6.0.1**.

Images available on Google Drive: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0Tg7BtjmCMqWXZZVXgwQy0xOXc/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0Tg7BtjmCMqX2dKbTBTaDMyblk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I was able to easily uninstall it from my android phone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a system app update from Alcatel. Recently they started updating some of their apps. I'm assuming you have an Idol 4 or 4S.

Although you can't uninstall or even fully disable this app, you can uninstall updates and stop automatic updates. Go to Settings - Apps - File manager. In the upper right-hand corner, push the three dots and click "Uninstall updates". Then go to Google Play - Your apps, click the file manager. Then in the right corner, click the three dots. Uncheck "Automatic updates". This will keep it from updating. You can do this with all of Alcatel apps.

I don't know why they thought having a purple octopus on the main screen a good idea but I and others have sent several emails regarding it and have been ignored.